# Display string that contains HTML code in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a string that contains the following HTML code:

```
             <div>
                <TextSubtitle [color]="'#B3B4B4'" [bold]="'true'">Datos Personales del Solicitante</TextSubtitle>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px;display: flex;justify-content: space-between">
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Primer nombre *'"></InputItem>
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Segundo nombre *'"></InputItem>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;display: flex;justify-content: space-between">
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Apellido paterno *'"></InputItem>
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Apellido materno *'"></InputItem>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;display: flex;justify-content: space-between">
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Fecha de nacimiento *'"></InputItem>
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Género *'"></InputItem>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;display: flex;justify-content: space-between">
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Ocupación *'"></InputItem>
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Dependientes económicos *'"></InputItem>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;display: flex;justify-content: space-between">
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Estado civil *'"></InputItem>
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'Número de hijos *'"></InputItem>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;display: flex;justify-content: space-between">
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'RFC *'"></InputItem>
                    <InputItem style="width: 47%" [label]="'CURP *'"></InputItem>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**note: InputItem is a angular component I build**

I am trying to insert the entire string as HTML code in my HTML file

typescript file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myString, "text/html");
  }
```

HTML file:

```
<div>
    {{doc.firstChild.innerHTML}}
</div>
```

this will print the actually HTML code as a string on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) and tell angular your content is safe with `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` method. Also you need to replace `firstChild.innerHTML` with `doc.body.outerHTML` if you would like to render the whole document.

Here is the sample on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chfq5m)

Comment: [innerHTML]= will only display the first html element with no styles

Comment: @I'mnothuman sure, it's because you use `firstChild.innerHTML`. Please, see my updated answer with an example on stackblitz